# If the "Truth" didn't exist, would that mean that feats such as Human Transmutation would work?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

In FMA Brotherhood, It is said that Truth watches over all alchemic exchanges in the world.

*The entity at the Gate calling itself Truth:*

[image]

My question is if Truth didn't exist would impossible feats such as Human Transmutation be *possible*? Would such a thing be possible?

Comment: I am nowhere close to 100% sure on this, but Truth, I think, while overseeing all alchemical exchanges, punishes those who attempt human transmutation, by dragging them through the gate and taking from them something they value (Ed's leg, Al's body and so on). Since a human's soul is still priceless in Alchemy, it will still not work, but without Truth, the one who attempts it will not be severely punished. All my humble opinion, though, don't hold me to it.

Comment: Probably the anime/manga itself wouldn't exist :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resurrections, a method of human transmutation, only has a problem with the soul. Since it is gone, you cannot call it back. Think of it like a chemical change, e.g. burning paper, you cannot restore it. The only real successful attempts of human transmutations are the homunculi though, but they still need souls too. To make up for the lack thereof, they run on Philosopher's Stones, which incidentally is made from trapped souls.

So Human Transmutation is possible. Just not all methods will achieve desired intent.

This is really simplified from memory of the show but should get the point across.

EDIT:
PS:
Alchemy is still used medicinally. You could argue that without Truth punishing people attempting to reclaim souls that at best they would just craft human shells or fresh corpses (as weird as that sounds). Remember, this is basically high-speed 3D printing.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Just the answer I was looking for.